# How do i build my android app in 64 libraries

Tags: eclipse, cocos2d-x, 32bit-64bit

i used **cocos2dx platform** and after i generate APK file and upload it in Google Play i received this message that my app doesn't support (arm64-v8a and x86_64) platforms ,i used **[eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjXQu.jpg)** by looking in lib folder i found only armeabi only how can i generate APK with 64 bit .I need to build my application for both 32bit (armeabi-v7a and x86) and 64bit (arm64-v8a and x86_64) platforms

Answer (score 0):

In the gradle.properties file you can set the architecture:

```
# List of CPU Archtexture to build that application with
# Available architextures (armeabi-v7a | arm64-v8a | x86)
# To build for multiple architexture, use the `:` between them
# Example - PROP_APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a:arm64-v8a:x86
PROP_APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a:arm64-v8a
```

Comment: "/usr/bin/bash: cannot execute binary file " i have this message